# Rounded top corners of bitmap android

Tags: android, bitmap, android-imageview

I am using this code to get top rounded corners of bitmap

```
public static void setTopRounded(Bitmap workingBitmap , int w, int h, ImageView v,Context context)
{
    Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(bmp);
    Shader shader = new BitmapShader(workingBitmap, Shader.TileMode.MIRROR,
            Shader.TileMode.MIRROR);

    Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setShader(shader);
    RectF rec = new RectF(0, 0, w, h - 20);
    c.drawRect(new RectF(0, 20, w, h), paint);
    c.drawRoundRect(rec, 10, 10, paint);
    v.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), bmp));
}
```

and my XML code for Image view is

```
<ImageView 
    android:layout_height="140dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/profileIV"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
```

now the problem is by setting

`v.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), bmp))`, 
`android:scaleType="centerCrop"`

property did not work and if i use

`v.setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), bmp))`

then scale type works but the image does not get rounded.
What i am doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you using both - drawRect() and drawRoundRect()?

Comment: setBackgroundDrawable() is deprecated.  Instead, use setBackground()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. I did not change any thing. Using the same function for top rounded corners image and use bitmap as background in image view. But now doing CenterCrop in code for imageView using ThumbnailUtils

First i use below function to get scaled CenterCroped image

```
Bitmap resizedProfileBitmap = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(profileBitmap, voucherTitleRLT.getWidth(), height);
```

and then use top rounded function to get set top rounded center croped image as background of imageview like below

```
setTopRounded(resizedProfileBitmap, resizedProfileBitmap.getWidth(), resizedProfileBitmap.getHeight(), profileIV, thisContext);
```

Comment: What Class does setTopRounded() belong to?

Answer (score 0):

Try  `v.setImageBitmap(bmp)` instead

Comment: Did this but same problem. Image did not get rounded.

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
     * This method used for bitmap compress and rounded corner
     * @param Bitmap object
     * @param pixels
     * @return nothing 
     */
    public static Bitmap getRoundedRectBitmap(final Bitmap bitmap,final  int pixels)
    {
        int color;
        float roundPx;
        final Bitmap    result = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);
        color = 0xff424242;
        final Paint paint = new Paint();
        final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
        final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);
        roundPx = pixels;
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
        paint.setColor(color);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paint);
        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);
        return result;
    }
```

//call the above method like this

**profileImage.setImageBitmap(getRoundedRectBitmap(bitmap, 50));**

Comment: just send your bitmap to this method and it will return rounded image.profileImage.setImageBitmap(getRoundedRectBitmap(bitmap, 50));

Comment: i have sent 50 as param because i need small image u can get big image by increasing the size

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in XML by creating a [Shape Drawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape) and setting it as the background on your ImageView.  This article explains how: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/pro-tip-round-corners-on-an-android-imageview-with-this-hack/#

Your shape drawable can look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<solid android:color="#00ffffff" />
<padding
    android:left="1dp"
    android:top="1dp"
    android:right="1dp"
    android:bottom="1dp" />
<corners
    android:topLeftRadius="6dp"
    android:topRightRadius="6dp"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="0.1dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="0.1dp" />
<stroke
    android:width="6dp"
    android:color="#ffffffff" />
```